# Giving access to execute SQL queries on a static database

Tags: postgresql, explain

I am working on a project where i want to give people the possibility to execute SQL queries on an PostgreSQL database. I then only need to prevent people from hacking/attacking my database.

I thought that maybe a way to do that, is by giving only view access to de database connection. And using EXPLAIN ANALYSE to calculating the cost of the SQL query.

Is EXPLAIN ANALYSE trustworthy enough to make sure there are no cheap ways to get the website down?

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: You can introduce login window, and their you can set privileges for all the users.
If anyone tries to hack/attack, you will know by their username/email.

Comment: Keeping it simple is not an bad idea! But Some cost calculation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN ANALYSE` will execute the query, including any side-effects it may have. PostgreSQL also allows running arbitrary Perl and Python code if configured to do so, so be careful. You're likely better off running PostgreSQL instances in per-request VMs or in similar highly isolated environments.

Comment: Does EXPLAIN ANALYSE only run on a small random subset of the query, or will it be as costly as running the fully query?

Comment: @kaibakker it will run the full query, as stated in the documentation.